# Can't run Selenium webdriver because of USB device and Bluetooth error

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Chromedriver\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get('https://www.tokopedia.com/search?st=product&q=ps%205&navsource=home')
```

Whenever I try run the code above I get the following errors :

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:62443/devtools/browser/4cc18177-e5fa-4ed8-b260-13c1670788e2
[3140:8180:0617/184053.599:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [18:40:53.599] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1058 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
[3140:8180:0617/184053.608:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [18:40:53.608] Bluetooth: bluetooth_adapter_winrt.cc:1072 Getting Default Adapter failed.
```

and the Chrome browser that should stay open closes itself. What is the cause and how do I fix it ? thanks!

Comment: Did you try adding chrome_options? 
`
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() \n
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/path/to/chromedriver", chrome_options=chrome_options)`

Answer (score 1):

Works for me after adding **chrome_options**

```
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/path/to/chromedriver", chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get('https://www.tokopedia.com/search?st=product&q=ps%205&navsource=home')
```

Comment: Tried that, still got the same error and browser force close unfortunately